# Asyncio running same task second time with different input shuts down first task too

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I have a script where I have multiple async functions and I am running them in loop. Everything runs okay, except one task which I need to run twice with different input parameters.

```
def run(self):
    checks_to_run = self.returnChecksBasedOnInputs()
    loop = asyncio.new_event_loop().run_until_complete(self.run_all_checks_async(checks_to_run))
    asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
    return self.output


async def run_all_checks_async(self,checks_to_run):
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        check_results = []
        for single_check in checks_to_run:
            if single_check == "cvim_check_storage":    #can run parallel in separate thread for each az
                total_number_of_azs = len(Constants.cvim_azs)+1
                self.log.info(total_number_of_azs)
                for x in range(1,total_number_of_azs):
                    task = asyncio.ensure_future(getattr(self, single_check)(session,x))
            else:
                task = asyncio.ensure_future(getattr(self, single_check)(session))
            check_results.append(task)
        await asyncio.gather(*check_results, return_exceptions=False)

class apiCaller:
    def __init__(self):
        pass
        
    async def callAndReturnJson(self, method, url, headers, session, payload, log):
        sslcontext = ssl.create_default_context(purpose=ssl.Purpose.CLIENT_AUTH)
        try:
            async with session.request(method, url, data=payload, headers=headers,ssl=sslcontext) as response:
                response = await response.json()
                print(str(response))
                return response
        except Exception as e:
            print("here exception")
            raise Exception(str(e))
```

The problem is here in this function - I am running it twice, but I noticed when the second version of the task goes to the return statement also first task closes down immediately. How can I avoid that and wait till other task also finishes ?

```
async def cvim_check_storage(self,session, aznumber):
        response = await apiCaller().callAndReturnJson("POST",f"https://{single_cvim_az}/v1/diskmgmt/check_disks",getattr(Constants,cvim_az_headers),session=session, payload=payload,log=self.log)
        self.log.info(str(response))
        self.log.info(str(response.keys()))
        if "diskmgmt_request" not in response.keys():
            self.output.cvim_checks.cvim_raid_checks.results[az_plus_number].overall_status = "FAILED"
            self.output.cvim_checks.cvim_raid_checks.results[az_plus_number].details = str(response)
        return 

        ...rest of the code if above if statement is false
```

Comment: You assign `task` inside a for loop (the inner one), but add it to `check_results` outside that loop. You’re only gathering the last task from the loop, not all of them.

Comment: @dirn if you kill me, that would be great, that was the issue

Comment: @dirn please post it as an asnwer

Comment: Posted. Glad it got things sorted for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is how you track your tasks. You are using `task` to add new tasks to `check_results`, but in one of your branches, you are assigning `task` inside a for loop. You don't add `task` to `check_results` until after the loop completes, though, so only the last task gets added. `gather` won't wait for any of the other tasks created before completing.

The solution is to add `task` during each iteration of the inner for loop. There are a few different ways to spell that.

One option is to just call `check_results.append` anywhere you currently assign to `task`.

```
if single_check == "cvim_check_storage":    #can run parallel in separate thread for each az
    total_number_of_azs = len(Constants.cvim_azs)+1
    self.log.info(total_number_of_azs)
    for x in range(1,total_number_of_azs):
        check_results.append(
            asyncio.ensure_future(getattr(self, single_check)(session,x))
        )
else:
    check_results.append(
        asyncio.ensure_future(getattr(self, single_check)(session))
    )
```

I'd take it one step further and use a list comprehension when creating multiple tasks, though.

```
if single_check == "cvim_check_storage":    #can run parallel in separate thread for each az
    total_number_of_azs = len(Constants.cvim_azs)+1
    self.log.info(total_number_of_azs)
    check_results.extend(
        [
            asyncio.ensure_future(getattr(self, single_check)(session,x))
            for x in range(1,total_number_of_azs)
        ]
    )
else:
    task = asyncio.ensure_future(getattr(self, single_check)(session))
    check_results.append(task)
```